# IPtables chain number persistence - how could I keep 1st rule on top?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-20.04, fail2ban

#### Summary

I'm trying to understand how to keep a rule on top of a chain in IPtables.  I'd like to keep my custom chain (as a rule) on top of the INPUT chain, that is, as the first rule in the chain.

#### Setup

- custom chain (which I want to keep on top of the INPUT chain)
- fail2ban which generates (I think creates and removes) chains based on status of bans

#### Current behaviour:

On setting up my custom chain, I can set it as rule number 1.
However, over time, with changes in fail2ban, the custom chain ends up being moved down the INPUT chain.

Thank you for your help! *My apologies if this has already been answered. I could not find it in the suggested questions unfortunately.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail2ban due to [this](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/08393f9d82d4929ce3ee09bd9f3c685d38b2428d/config/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf#L19) line (for example in `iptables-multiport`) will add the rule at first plaice in the `INPUT` chain, which would interpolate to this line normally (e. g. simple sshd jail, IPv4, etc):

```bsh
# <iptables> -I <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j f2b-<name>
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
```

So you have 2 possibilities to do this:

1. either you create another chain (e. g. `F2B`), add it after your first chain in INPUT and specify its name in fail2ban config instead INPUT. For example create new [/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-common.local](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/08393f9d82d4929ce3ee09bd9f3c685d38b2428d/config/action.d/iptables-common.conf#L34) and overwrite the `chain` with your own for all fail2ban chains:

```
[Init]
chain = F2B
```

or specify its name in `jail.local`, for example in default section or per jail:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = %(known/banaction)s[chain=F2B]
banaction_allports = %(known/banaction_allports)s[chain=F2B]
```

2. Specify own rule number (1 is default) in the chain. So instead of set chain to `F2B`, use `chain = INPUT 2` in local common configuration or like here in `jail.local`:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = %(known/banaction)s[chain="INPUT 2"]
banaction_allports = %(known/banaction_allports)s[chain="INPUT 2"]
```

In this case fail2ban will interpolated abovementioned adding rule (for sshd jail) like this:

```
- iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
+ iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
```

Just in both cases ensure (e. g. using service dependencies) that the chain `F2B` and your own chain are already added to iptables (fail2ban will start after your change is already made).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @sebres ! You've got me covered!